# Can't pull image with Error x509: certificate signed by unknown authority in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I practice about kubernetes using minikube

I make docker-registry as a pods and I create docker-registry service

**edit /etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
{
"insecure-registries":["192.168.99.100:30050"]
}
```

**edit openssl.conf**

```
[v3_req]
subjectAltName = IP:192.168.99.100
```

**And I make certificate**

```
openssl genrsa -out my.crt
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key my.key -subj "CN=192.168.99.100:30050" -days 5000 -out my.crt
```

**create registry-tls-secret**

```
kubectl create secret generic registry-tls-secret --from-file=my.crt=my.crt --from-file=my.key=my.key
```

**and make directory and copy my.crt file into the directory**

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.99.100:30050
```

So I can push & pull 192.168.99.100:30050/[image]:[tag] on the host

And After I try to make hello-world pods

hello-world image is into the docker-registry(192.168.99.100:30050) already

I create secrets docker-registry regcred

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=192.168.99.100:30050 --docker-usernmae=<user-name> --docker-password=<user-password> --docker-email=<user-email>
```

and write helloworld-deployment.yaml

```
...
    image: 192.168.99.100:30050/hello-world:v1
...
imagePullSecrets:
  -name: regcred
...
```

Finally I apply helloworld-deployment.yaml
But I got an error message that

```
Failed to pull image "192.168.99.100:30050/hello-world:v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.99.100:30050/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

**I don't really what I'm missing... please help me...**

Comment: did you restart `docker` after? Could you describe which host did you mean by "on the host"? The Pods which are controlled by your deployment are scheduled to a one of your nodes. So docker should be configured the similar all over the nodes

Comment: Since you are using self signed certificate , you need to tell the docker client about the CA certificate that you used to create the certificates for docker registry , in this case you docker client doesnt know about the CA you used for docker registry certs.

Comment: can you ping your docker registry from the minikube vm?

Comment: I set minikube by virtualbox on ubuntu 16.04. "on the host" is ubuntu 16.04. Have i  store the CA certificate in the minikube VM???

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for storing a port number in the certificate so Common Name of the certificate should not contain a port. Create Certificate with `CN=192.168.99.100` and repeat same steps. For more information on common name refer [here](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/).

Make sure you Copy the certificate data to `/etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.99.100:30050/ca.crt`.

Comment: I don't know /etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.99.100:30050/ is a host or VM...